# how to omit the middleware of a specific route in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following route:

`Route::get('table_position/{discipline}/{category}', 'ProgrammingController@v_table')->name('programming.v_table');`

but I want it to be displayed without needing to authenticate.

Use the php artisan make: auth so it takes the auth middleware.

I'm using laravel 5.7

I want you to allow me to visualize without needing to authenticate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a little change in your `ProgrammingController` like this way,

```
class ProgrammingController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
     $this->middleware('auth')->except(['v_table']);
   }
}
```

By defining on which specific `function` you dont want to use `auth` middleware by passing an `array` of `function name`.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what Authenticates your process is this

```
if (Auth::check()){
    //everything
}
```

So if you don't call this in ProgrammingController@v_table then it shouldn't authenticate unless you are requiring the Auth::check further up the route. Make sure you check your index and your base controller for the Auth::check()